# Does omxplayer have a silent mode?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, omxplayer

I am doing a little project which requires omxplayer on the Raspberry Pi to not output any information.

I am wondering if omxplayer has a silent mode, like fswebcam does or if there is any way to disable any output like the audio file selected and the bitrate...

I will thank you so much if you can give me a good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the **--no-osd** flag. This tells omxplayer not to display status information on the screen.

You can find info like this using the man command:

```
man omxplayer
```

This displays the man (manual) page. You can read more about the man command on our [blog](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/141758901139/improving-your-command-line-skills-part-1).

You can also use the old standby and redirect the standout to /dev/null using the following command:

```
omxplayer example.mp3 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Ok @Steve Robillard, I tried the **--no-osd** flag, but it seems to have absolutely no effect whatsoever. It still shows the usual:                                                Audio codec pcm_s16le channels 2 samplerate 44100 bitspersample 16
Subtitle count: 0, state: off, index: 1, delay: 0
have a nice day ;)

Comment: Am I putting the flag in the wrong place or something??

Comment: @K.Dubey I just tried it and the flag did not have any effect either, I have edited my answer and tested the redirect method I added to my answer.

Comment: Thank you! This worked brilliantly thank you so much! :)